# Stat2Data package doesn't allow me to use the objects in it

Tags: package

Stat2Data package contains a lot of exemplary datasets. I get no errors when installing it or using the library function to call it. However, it doesn't allow me to work with the objects.

Anyone familiar with this package and know what I can do about it? Here's the code that I used:

```
install.packages("Stat2Data")
library(Stat2Data)

# Attempt 1
MedGPA_ds <- ggplot(MedGPA, aes(x = GPA, y = Acceptance))

# Attempt 2
MedGPA_ds <- ggplot(Stat2Data::MedGPA, aes(x = GPA, y = Acceptance))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed just one step, the use of the `data()` function to call the specific dataset (MedGPA) contained within the Stat2Data package.

Try the following:

```
library(Stat2Data)
data(MedGPA)
head(MedGPA)      
  Accept Acceptance Sex BCPM  GPA VR PS WS BS MCAT Apps
1      D          0   F 3.59 3.62 11  9  9  9   38    5
2      A          1   M 3.75 3.84 12 13  8 12   45    3
3      A          1   F 3.24 3.23  9 10  5  9   33   19
4      A          1   F 3.74 3.69 12 11  7 10   40    5
5      A          1   F 3.53 3.38  9 11  4 11   35   11
6      A          1   M 3.59 3.72 10  9  7 10   36    5
```

Happy coding!